# onTouchListener is not working in 4.0 above version of android but it is working in below

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-4.2-jelly-bean, ontouchlistener

Hi I have implemented ontouchlistener in my service class  and trying to get the touch event which is working well with android 2.3 but it is not working with higher version. I am trying a lot to solve this but I am not getting any solution even after reading a lot of documents in stackoverflow, Here is the code ..please help me solve this problem

in onCreate method I have defined Image Button

```
    ImageButton imageButton=new ImageButton(this);
imageButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
imageButton.setOnTouchListener(this);

    @Override public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Double touched "+DoubleTouch, 1000).show();
return false;
}
```

Comment: There is no Android version 2.6

Comment: There is no official version of Android 2.6

Comment: ok thanks, plz suggest on solving the above problem

Answer (score 0):

you want use code`imageButton.setOnTouchListener(youActivityname.this);`

Comment: Hi @saravanan thanks for your kindness, I have implemented this also but it is not working, actually I have implemented onTouchListener in a service class